# Correct name: card-parser or cards-parser

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural, plural-forms, attributive-nouns, attributives

There is a program that parses site pages with information about cards (there are many of them on the page). The program can be called card-parser or cards-parser. Which option is preferred and why?
I like card-parser because it's shorter, but the program parses many cards.
Translator says that any variant is correct, but I don't understand, why some not-english-native-speakers use 'cards-parser' then.

Comment: Have you searched anywhere (on this site, elsewhere online, in books, etc.) for the difference between singular and plural attributive nouns? There are many discussions of this issue that are very easy to find.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan thank you. Now I found what I need by 'singular and plural attributive nouns' search query.

Answer (score 1):

"parser" is a countable noun and singular, so it should be the below even if multiple cards are processed

> card-parser

E.g. You don't say

> computers-translator

You say

> computer-translator